# Grouping the multiple value corresponding to single Key in csv file using AWK

Tags: awk

While grouping the values corresponding to single key, I tried this on on a csv format file having more than two fields like :

```
Keyobject,FieldName,Fieldvalue
1,are you sleeping,yes
1,country of meeting,USA 
2,are you sleeping,' '
2,country of meeting,' '
3,are you sleeping,yes
3,country of meeting,CHINA
4,are you sleeping,yes
4,country of meeting,ITALY
```

Expected Output :

```
Keyobject,Are you sleeping,country of meeting
1,yes,USA
2, ,
3,yes,CHINA
4,no,ITALY.
```

Please do provide the rough idea or any script .

Comment: @Dinesh Boora. you have discrepancy between input and output. For instance, row#4 the response is `yes` not `no` as presented in the output. row #2 in the output must be `',' ' '` please revise the question accordingly!

Comment: This will print the fieldvalue's with a matching keyobject of 1
`cat file.csv | awk -F, '$1 == "1" {printf $3","}'`

I tried to loop each unique keyobject but im having trouble getting this awk statement to print the output at all.

What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '
    NR > 1 {ids[$1]; keys[$2]; value[$1,$2] = $3}
    END { 
        printf "Keyobject"
        for (k in keys)
            printf ",%s", k
        print ""

        for (id in ids) {
            printf id
            for (k in keys)
                printf ",%s", value[id,k]
            print ""
        }
    }
' file
```

Comment: `for(key in array)` may iterate through the keys in any order. with `original-awk` (actually `nawk`) the lines will be printed 2,3,4,1.

Comment: @glenn jackman  this is brilliant !!

Comment: Hi jackman,

many thanks for your prompt response. I have tried the script provided above but output seems not containing the first two fields.
output what i got is below:

,USA 
 , ' '
 ,CHINA
 ,ITALY

can you please suggest ?

Comment: Looks like your input files have `\r\n` line endings. Run `dos2unix` on the input files

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your csv file is called "list.csv". I would do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "Keyobject","Are you sleeping ", " Country of meeting"   # create new header
cat list.csv | sed 1,1d | awk -F, 'NF>1{print $NF}' | paste -d', ' - - | sed 's/ /,/' | nl


 1  yes,USA 
 2  ' ', ' '
 3  yes,CHINA
 4  yes,ITALY
```

Explanation:

```
sed 1,1d # This command excludes the original header in list.csv
awk -F, 'NF>1{print $NF}' # This command reads the last word in each row
paste -d', ' - -  # This command paste the words beside each other 
sed 's/ /,/'  # This command replaces blank spaces with commas
nl # This command adds numbering to the rows in the final output
```

However, this solution assumes that the rows in the original csv file are organized as presented in your example above.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk <file -v IV="' '" -v OV=" " -F, '
        $1+0 {
                b = $2 == IV ? OV : $2
                a[$1,$2] = $3 == IV ? OV : $3
                if($1 > max) max = $1; t[$2]++;
        }
        END{
                ORS = ""
                print "Keyobject"
                for(k in t) print FS k
                print RS
                for(i = 1; i <= max; i++){
                        print i
                        for(k in t)
                                print FS (i SUBSEP k in a ? a[i,k] : OV)
                        print RS
                }
        }
'
```

Adjust the `IV` and `OV` variables for what an empty field should be in the input and output respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '
NR == 1                 {HD      = "Keyobject,are you sleeping,country of meeting"
                         for (MX=n=split (HD, HDArr, OFS); n>0; n--) SRCH[HDArr[n]]
                         print HD
                         next
                        }


$2 in SRCH              {RES[$2] = $3
                         RES[HDArr[1]] = $1
                        }

NR%2                    {for (i=1; i<=MX; i++) printf "%s%s", RES[HDArr[i]], (i == MX)?ORS:OFS
                         split ("", RES)
                        }

' file
Keyobject,are you sleeping,country of meeting
1,yes,USA 
2,' ',' '
3,yes,CHINA
4,yes,ITALY
```

When reading line 1, the header, and a search array indexed by the header elements is created, and header printed. In the lines following, the results array indexed by $2 is assigned $3, and redundantly for the "Keyobject" index string. For every second line, the result is printed, and the result array deleted.